# Perl: Unable to exec

Tags: perl, exec, fork

I am trying to run few child processes on different platforms in parallel. Parent should only proceed further once all the child processes have completed on respective platforms.

The problem is that when I use fork and then run the ‘exec’ command in the child process, it ends almost instantly. Also, the output isn't consistent. Almost every time the log shows only one line.

```
-bash-2.05b$ cat Agent.SOLSPARC
caught SIGTERM signal, cleaning up
```

or

```
-bash-2.05b$ cat Agent.SOLSPARC
Host: EBSO9SPC  Login: esm2
```

Sometimes, there are few extra lines and at last the message, '*Killed by signal 15'*. The command that i use in 'exec' actually calls a script which connects to remote boxes and runs make command on them. For testing purpose, i am currently passing only one platform i.e., SOLSPARC. Also, i'm only interested in knowing whether a command finished on any given platform.

I was not sure whether I was passing all the arguments to ‘exec’ correctly so I tried different combinations (after referring different links on the Internet) but to no avail. One important observation is that when i used strace to debug this issue, the command worked fine. I saw in the perldoc that exec uses */bin/sh -c* on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms. Is it that exec and strace use different shell?

Here’s the relevant portion of my code:

```
sub compile {
    my %child_pids;
    foreach $plat (0 .. $#plat_list) {
        my $pid = fork;
        # Didn't check the undef condition for child
        if ($plat_list[$plat] eq "SOLSPARC") {
            print "\nStarted Solaris build \n";
            if ($pid == 0) {
                print "Inside Child Process \n\n";
                exec ( "${ROOT}/${REM_EXEC} -t 1200 -c \"make LANG=en_US distclean \" -b ${ROOT} -l Agent. $plat_list[$plat]" ) or die "exec failed";
            } elsif ($pid > 0) {
                $child_pids{"SOLSPARC"} = $pid;
            }
        } else {
           print "\nStarted build for other platforms \n";
           if ($pid == 0) {
                print "Inside Child Process \n\n";
                exec ( "${ROOT}/${REM_EXEC} -t 1200 -c \"make LANG=en_GB clean \" -b ${ROOT} -l Agent. $plat_list[$plat]" ) or die "exec failed";     
           } elsif ($pid > 0) {
                $child_pids{"$plat_list[$plat]"} = $pid;
           }
        }
    }


    my %rev_child_pids = reverse %child_pids;
    while ((my $kid = waitpid -1, WNOHANG) > 0) {
        if ($rev_child_pids{$kid} eq "SOLSPARC") {
            print "\nChild process completed for SOLARIS platform $rev_child_pids{$kid} \n";
            print "Run some other command here \n";
        } else {
            print "\nChild process completed for other platform $rev_child_pids{$kid} \n";
            print "No more commands to run \n";
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably be using the 'list form' of [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), passing in a list of arguments instead of a single string.  This avoids executing the shell to run the command.

Comment: Just to add to Jonathan's note, avoiding shell only works if your command line parameters do NOT have any special shell characters, such as `<`, `|`, etc...

Comment: @DVK is right, but there's also a security concern that if you aren't careful about variables like `${ROOT}`, `${REM_EXEC}`, etc. you can end up with some really awesome exploits in your code. That might not seem like a huge deal for a command-line script, but consider this: Let's say `${ROOT}` is the name of a file on the file system you pick up automatically and that file just happens to be named "`;rm -rf /*;`", you might be unhappy with the results. Using multi-argument exec avoids that particular problem.

Comment: I tried the following two forms but still there is no change in output. `exec ( "${ROOT}/${REM_EXEC}", "-t 1200", "-c \"make LANG=en_US distclean \"", "-b ${ROOT}", "-l Agent.", "$plat_list[$plat]" ) or die "exec failed";` and `exec ( "${ROOT}/${REM_EXEC}", "-t", "1200", "-c", "\"make LANG=en_US distclean \"", "-b", "${ROOT}", "-l", "Agent.", "$plat_list[$plat]" ) or die "exec failed";` I had tried these forms before also.

Comment: You need to show us the smallest complete code that reproduces the symptoms.  (For example, are you spawning nmap somewhere?  That would explain the "caught SIGTERM..." message.)

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in reply. Was on leave. To add to it, my script call a compiled binary and i wasn't aware where the source was. :P Anyways, i have it now. @pilcrow: Yes, you're right; the script uses nmap. Here's the source: http://pastebin.com/j4MJgPPL

Comment: Update: I got around this issue by using [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.9/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm) module. Looks like, using basics ('fork') was a wrong choice (for me) at least for this issue. I should have left it for the modules in the first place. Will _fork_ some other day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'system' instead of 'exec'.

```
system `${ROOT}/${REM_EXEC} -t 1200 -c "make LANG=en_US distclean " -b ${ROOT} -l Agent. $plat_list[$plat]`
```

'system' works slightly differently in relation to fork so it might solve the problem.